# Get the content from currencyconverterapi

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have currency rate.
I want get currency val from this link by jquery 
http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.getJSON` like below to read an print the currency

```js
$.getJSON("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y", function(response) {
  $("#result").html(response.EUR_USD.val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y", function(result) {
    $("#rate").text(result.EUR_USD.val);
});
```

Comment: can you show full example. get val and display by <div id="rate"> </div>